# How to set timeout for get request using Axios in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios

How can I set a timeout for a GET request using axios in Vue.js and Webpack?
For example I have this code

```
axios.get("myURL").then(function(response) {
        // code 
    }
```

I have tried to include {timeout:3000} as parameter but it doesn't work

Comment: `axios.get("myURL", { timeout: 3000 })` should work, are there any errors displaying in console?

Comment: No I have no errors. I have tried to create an axios instance axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'myURL',
  timeout: 5000,
})   but I still have no timeout.. I get only only once response

Comment: But why would you get it more than once?

Comment: I want to send a new GET request every 5 sec to test the data. The JSON I get has random data that changes every time I send a request..

Comment: Then you are looking for `setInterval`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval axios' `timeout` is used to "cancel" the request if the response doesn't arrive in X ms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the `timeout` in Axios is a `response timeout`, not a `connect timeout`. You can try using the `cancelToken` feature

```
const connectToServer = ip => {
    let source = CancelToken.source();
    setTimeout(() => {
        source.cancel();
    }, 3000);
    return axios.get(ip + '/config', {cancelToken: source.token}).then((result) => {
        // My logic
    })
};
```

which will cancel always, or if you want to cancel only if there was no response:

```
function loginButtonPressed(username, password) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const source = CancelToken.source();
        try {
            let response = null;
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (response === null) {
                    source.cancel();
                }
            }, 4000);
            dispatch(authenticationPending());

            response = await axios.post('auth/login',
                {username, password},
                {cancelToken: source.token});
            dispatch(authenticationSuccess());
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(authenticationFailed());
        }
    };
}
```